# Given a r.v. Uniform in [0,1], What is the distribution of 1-U?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

I have an excercise and would like to know if the way I've solved it is correct or not
Given $U \sim \mathcal{Uniform}(0,1)$ What is the distribution of $X = 1-U$
My solution is..
$$
P(X\leq u)=\\
P(1-U \leq u)=\\
P(1-u \leq U)=\\
1-P(U \leq 1-u)=\\
1 - \int_{0}^{1-u}1du=\\
1 - (1 - u)=\\
u
$$
So $F_x(u)=u$ and therefore, the pdf is $f_x(u)=1$
It is just another Uniform(0,1)

Is the procedure correct? Am I missing something?
Thanks a lot in advance for any commment!

Comment: makes sense to me

Comment: Just compute directly since you know the pdf: If $\alpha \in [0,1]$ then $P[1-U \le \alpha] = P[1-\alpha \le U] = \int_{1-\alpha}^1 d \alpha = \alpha$.

Comment: @copper.hat Oh it's true, I didn't take that into account. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind $U=\phi(X)=1-X$ is a decreasing function, so when you want to find $P(\phi(X)<u) = P(X>\phi^{-1}(u))$, i.e. the inequality sign changes.

Comment: So you say..$$P(X \leq x) = P(\Phi(X) \geq \Phi(x)) =  P(1-U \geq 1-u)$$

Comment: In my solution I flipped $X$ and $U$. Keep in mind that $\phi(U) = 1-U$ and $\phi^{-1}(x) = 1-x$ (note upper-case for rvs and lowercase for arguments). I suggest that you plot $U=U(X)$ and $X=X^{-1}(U)$ and mark the areas that correspond to the required inequalities. You will see it straight away.